# Cloudfront s3 Nextjs website sometimes does not load correctly on the browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, browser, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I am facing a weird issue that only appears to some browser or some clients.
I have developped a full static website using Nextjs. The website is deployed on cloudfront - S3.
Sometimes, when the client click on the link, a broken page appears as if the Javascript package were not loaded correctly.
For information, this website is build twice a day and a new version is pushed to the cloudfront distribution.
I do not know wether this issue is related to cache (when we refresh, the website loads correclty) and I have no idea where to start to solve it...

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you [invalidate the CloudFront cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#Invalidation_Requests) for the overwritten files after uploading your new version?

Comment: Yes I do, I specify this path : /*

Comment: hmm...  not sure what your issue could be. Post an error output from the browser, otherwise we are fishing in the dark.

Comment: After browsing I realized that those errors appear on Mac. On the console it is written “cannot read property of undefined at several places

Comment: And on safari I am getting a minified react error

Comment: I found it ! It has nothing to do with the cache -> the fact is that we are using redux and persist store in the app, and the previous persist:store was not compatible with the new one, so it raises erros.